# Problem iterating in dictionary with numeric keys

Tags: python-3.x, loops, dictionary

I want to iterate over a nested dictionary whose main keys are integers. When I try to assign values to a specific key, the value is assigned to all of them.

here is an example of the code assigned values directly and another by iterating

```
import numpy as np
dic={}.fromkeys(np.arange(3),{'key1':[],'key2':[], 'key3':[]})
list1=[0.9, 0.8, 0.7]

dic[0]['key1'].append(list1[0])
dic[1]['key1'].append(list1[1])
dic[2]['key1'].append(list1[2])

for i in dic.keys():
    dic[i]['key3'].append(list1[i])

dic
```

and this is the output

```
{0: {'key1': [0.9, 0.8, 0.7], 'key2': [], 'key3': [0.9, 0.8, 0.7]},
 1: {'key1': [0.9, 0.8, 0.7], 'key2': [], 'key3': [0.9, 0.8, 0.7]},
 2: {'key1': [0.9, 0.8, 0.7], 'key2': [], 'key3': [0.9, 0.8, 0.7]}}
```

It is probably a trivial error but I have not been able to fix it. Thanks

I was expecting something like this

```
{0: {'key1': [0.9], 'key2': [], 'key3': [0.9]},
 1: {'key1': [0.8], 'key2': [], 'key3': [0.8]},
 2: {'key1': [0.7], 'key2': [], 'key3': [0.7]}}
```